# On MacOSX, why do I need to specify GEM_HOME with '-n' arg on install commands?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

On MacOSX, why do I need to specify GEM_HOME with '-n' arg on install commands?  **Can this be changed?  If so, how?**

```
sudo gem install bundler -n /usr/local/bin
```

When I don't use the '-n', I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/bundle
```

Setting a GEM_HOME env does not seem to affect the behavior.

Here is my env:

```
blah@machine /Library/Ruby $ sudo gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/blah/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/blah/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
```

Comment: Are you setting GEM_HOME env to **/usr/local/bin** or to **/usr/bin/bundle**?

Comment: Are you using **rvm** or **rbenv**? This seems to me an issue related to permissions. If you use these two installers, they will do all operations in user space and then you won't have permission issues. Much easier this way.